# Stream Data through Ruby Script and using parameter in ARGV

Tags: ruby, streaming

I need to stream data through a Ruby script, and will be calling this program from my terminal like so:

```
cat file.txt | ruby example.rb
```

The code inside `example.rb` looks like this:

```
ARGF.each do |line|
  #program logic
end
```

This program works fine, but now I need to pass one (or potentially more) parameters to `example.rb`.  I can't use trollop or optparser (or anything of that nature).  I am trying to pass my parameter to my program like this:

```
cat file.txt | ruby example.rb 2
```

I am trying to use this parameter in my program by extracting it from the ARGV array:

```
x = ARGV.first
puts x

ARGF.each do |line|
  #program logic
end
```

But now the program gives me this error:

```
No such file or directory - 2
```

I seems like ARGF is using now using the parameter as my standard input instead of the file that I am streaming to it.  How can I use pass ARGV and ARGF together like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/ARGF.html):

The arguments passed to your script are stored in the ARGV Array, one argument per element. ARGF assumes that any arguments that aren't filenames have been removed from ARGV. For example:

```
$ ruby argf.rb --verbose file1 file2

ARGV  #=> ["--verbose", "file1", "file2"]
option = ARGV.shift #=> "--verbose"
ARGV  #=> ["file1", "file2"]
```

You can now use `ARGF` to work with a concatenation of each of these named files. For instance, `ARGF.read` will return the contents of `file1` followed by the contents of `file2`.